# Оформление программы, свой дизайн

Tags: интерфейс, delphi

Есть простая форма, мне нужно её украсить так, как я нарисовал макет в Adboe Photoshop. Как лучше будет реализовать картинку (макет) в живой интерфейс программы?

1. Какие способы сейчас более актуальны?
2. С помощью Canvas'a можно все это сделать или я ошибаюсь?
3. Касательно картинок. Слышал, что некоторые умельцы делают весь дизайн с помощью нарезки картинок из Adobe Photoshop. Насколько это будет правильно?

P.S. Материала много в Интернете, но везде говорят по-разному и противоречат друг другу. Хотелось бы услышать мнение "в живую".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модно и правильно делать так, чтобы программа выглядела естественно.

Не у всех хорошее зрение, не у всех выставлены стандартные настройки и много-много чего. Даже не у всех версий виндов одинаковое поведение.